# TF cidr_block proper string

Tags: terraform

I am running a tf deployment and running into an issue. See my codes below and let me know if something is off.
My TF client version --> `1.0.4`

`private_subnet/variables.tf`

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name to prepend to the resource/tags in amazon EBS"
}

variable "enable_public_ip" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Whether the nodes should be given public IPs."
}

variable "external_ip_list" {
  type        = list
  description = "The ip that is allowed to talk to the nodes from external."
}

variable "vpc" {
  description = "The vpc to use"
}

variable "nat_gateway" {
  description = "nat gateway to direct traffic to"
}

variable "internet_gateway" {
  description = "Internet gateway for outbound ipv6 traffic"
}

variable "cidr_blocks" {
  type    = list
  default = ["172.xx.x.x/xx", "172.xx.xx.x/xx", "172.xx.xx.x/xx"]
}
```

`private_subnet/subnets.tf`

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available_az" {
  state = "available"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc.id
  count      = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.zone_ids)
  cidr_block = var.cidr_blocks[count.index]

  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ip
  availability_zone_id    = data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.zone_ids[count.index]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${terraform.workspace}-${var.name}-subnet-${count.index}"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

`main.tf`

```
module "k8s_cluster" {
  source           = "./k8s_cluster"
  name             = var.k8s_cluster_name
  enable_public_ip = var.enable_public_ip
  vpc              = module.k8s_vpc.vpc
  security_groups  = module.public_network.security_groups # [module.public_network.security_group_map["external_ports"]]
  subnets          = module.private_network.private_subnets
  k8s_size         = var.k8s_size
  k8s_ami          = var.k8s_ami
}

module "bastion" {
  source          = "./bastion"
  name            = var.bastion_node_name
  node_count      = var.bastion_count
  security_groups = [module.public_network.security_group_map["ssh_sg"]]
  subnets         = module.public_network.public_subnets
  k8s_size        = var.k8s_size
  k8s_ami         = var.k8s_ami
}

module "ceph_storage" {
  source      = "./k8s_storage"
  nodes       = concat(module.k8s_cluster.worker_nodes) #, module.master.nodes)
  name        = var.ceph_storage_name
  device_name = var.ceph_device_name
}

module "k8s_vpc" {
  source     = "./vpc"
  name       = var.vpc_name
  cidr_block = var.cidr_block
  nodes      = concat(module.k8s_cluster.worker_nodes)
}

module "public_network" {
  source              = "./public_subnet"
  name                = "public" #var.network_name
  external_ip_list    = var.external_ip_list
  disable_nat_gateway = var.enable_public_ip
  vpc                 = module.k8s_vpc.vpc
}

module "private_network" {
  source           = "./private_subnet"
  name             = "private" # var.network_name
  enable_public_ip = var.enable_public_ip
  external_ip_list = var.external_ip_list
  vpc              = module.k8s_vpc.vpc
  nat_gateway      = module.public_network.nat_gateway
  internet_gateway = module.public_network.internet_gateway
}
```

The error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.54.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v3.54.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on private_subnet/subnets.tf line 8, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnet":
│    8:   cidr_block = var.cidr_blocks[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 5
│     │ var.cidr_blocks is list of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on private_subnet/subnets.tf line 8, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnet":
│    8:   cidr_block = var.cidr_blocks[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 3
│     │ var.cidr_blocks is list of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on private_subnet/subnets.tf line 8, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnet":
│    8:   cidr_block = var.cidr_blocks[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 4
│     │ var.cidr_blocks is list of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: `length(data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.zone_ids)` is six elements long and var.cidr_blocks is 3 elements long. Does var.cidr_blocks need to be an indexed list? It seems like you could use a constant.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily this is a sandbox account so it's fine I just want to pass this blocker and run the codes. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using one array to index another, and you're not doing anything to ensure that they're the same length, so you're getting overflow errors.

This change will be equivalent, and avoid the issue.

`private_subnet/subnets.tf`

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc.id
  count      = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.zone_ids)
  cidr_block = "172.xx.xx.x/xx"

  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ip
  availability_zone_id    = data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.zone_ids[count.index]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${terraform.workspace}-${var.name}-subnet-${count.index}"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, injecting one cidr as you mentioned worked? What about if I want to inject 3 cidr instead of one? I tried `cidr_block = ["172.32.x.x/xx", "172.32.xx.x/xx", "172.32.xx.x/xx"]` with no luck

Comment: A subnet takes one cidr block. What you need is a way to make sure that you count out your subnets and have enough cidr blocks for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; in my case it was just the random dumb-assery of too many experiments. I set conflicting values for parameter in both:

- terraform.tfvars (integer: 4), and
- an environmental variable (integer: 3)

```bash
# Verifying the environment variable
% echo $TF_VAR_minDistSize | terraform console
3

# Verifying what it looks like in Terraform's memory space
% echo var.minDistSize | terraform console                                                                                                                                      
4
```

TF was understandable confused. The data source I used to lookup AZs pulled back a total of 3 (which I set as an ENV var); however, I also told TF to build 4. (eye_roll)

I hope this helps someone `:-)` it was super easy fix that took way to long to find.

For all else, I like @Dan Monego's answer for the real solution.